# Running multiple instances of the same application using .NET multithreading

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multithreading, process, multiple-instances

I have two .NET applications. One is a standalone console application that launches multiple instances of the second application, passing each one different array of arguments. I start the second application using Process.Start.

I need to ensure that each app instance has its own space in memory and I am thinking of creating a new thread to run each app. I am pretty new to multithreading and was wondering if this is a good practice? Are there better way to do that? Can multiple instances of the same app run side by side without any issues?  I'd appreciate any help. thanks!

Here is partial code from the launching app:
arr is an array containing multiple string values. the code below takes those values in increments equal to iCount, puts them into a temp array - arrTemp and passes it to the second application:

```
i = 0

While (i <= arr.Count - 1)
    j = 0
    ReDim arrTemp(iCount-1)
    While j < iCount And j < arr.Count - 1
        arrTemp(j) = arr(i).ToString()
        j += 1
        i += 1
    End While

  'pass an array to the process as an argument
   startInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", arrTemp)
   Dim p As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
   p.WaitForExit()

   'clear the array
    ClearArray(arrTemp)

    i = j + 1
End While
```

I want to add multithreading to the code above to enable the app to spawn multiple instances of the second app. I also need some help with that

Comment: they all have their own space in memory since they are running in different processes.

Comment: Assuming the second app is properly using any shared resources, just get rid of `p.WaitForExit()` and you'll have multiple instances running...

Comment: Idle Mind, just to clarify, the Process.Start will do the job and I do not need to use multithreading? Are there any advantages of creating separate processes with threading?

Comment: They will all run concurrently, yes.  Whether this is safe, or beneficial, I have no idea as I don't know the details of the code.  You mentioned in comments below that you're processing a large number of files.  If this is the case then opening too many instances might be detrimental as then the hard drive will have to keep moving back and forth between files as the operating system time slices each process and has to fetch more data from a different place on the hard drive.  The only way to really know is to test it under different conditions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Running processes in separate threads" as a concept doesn't make any sense. Processes contain threads; not the other way around. A process also has it's own "space in memory" (whilst a thread does not!), so it makes no difference in that regard, either.

If you launch a process using `Process.Start`, it's going to run completely separately of your code (completely outside of any threads you have access to) and with its own memory space.

The only reason you might need multiple threads is that, in the specific code you've posted, you're waiting for the application to exit before the code can continue. That means you're blocking the thread while the application runs, and for that reason alone you might want multiple threads. (That said, you might be better off refactoring the code so that it'll run on a single thread.)

As far as the safety of running multiple instances of the application is concerned: that depends totally on the application. A dozen notepad instances will run side-by-side with no problem, but that's not true of all applications.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am processing a large amount of files so my app (second app in this case) is running for a very long time. I want to try to process some of the files simultaneously, so I wanted to do this with running multiple instances of the application at the same time. My posted code splits the files in the increments of iCount (for test purposes 10 or 20). Can you suggest a better way to do what I am trying to do? I'd really appreciate any tips

Comment: Something like this: instead of calling `p.WaitForExit` where you do, add all of your `p`s to a `List(Of Process)`. Then, after your existing loop, use a `For Each` to call `.WaitForExit` on each process in your list. That allows all of your processes to be started at once, and will wait for them all to finish before continuing. That would give you a simple improvement over the current code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notepad.exe can run multiple independent instances and so can your app. No modifications whatsoever are necessary. By default, instances are isolated from each other and share nothing.

Comment: could you help me to add threading to my loop so that multiple processes are spawned separately?

Comment: Why are you waiting for them to exit?

Comment: You can't guarantee that an application will run multiple instances without side effects. Some apps explicitly prevent this; some apps might use shared data (files, registry, database) that aren't designed/coded to be multiple use. It really depends on the application.

Comment: @DanPuzey that is all true but since he did not investigate this issue before he probably does not prevent multiple instances.